# How should I create a backbone collection scoped to another model?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a post which has many comments, and I want to display the comments on the post page. This is a Rails 3 application and I have my comments' URLs nested in the post's URL, so it basically looks like `/post/1/comments`.

The problem is, I'm not really sure how should I create a backbone collection for this situation. Should I just pass the `post_id` to the javascript form the server and then do something like

```
var Comments = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Comment,
  url: '/post/' + idFromSomewhereElse + '/comments'
});
```

or is there a better way to handle this? How should I handle this in case of multiple nesting, where I could have something like `/forums/1/topics/3/replies`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One idea could be to *delegate* the *root* of the `Comments.url` to the `Post` parent model:

```
// code simplified and not tested
App.Post = Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot: "/posts"
});

App.Comments = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Comment,

  urlRoot: function(){
    return this.post.url + "/comments";
  },

  initialize: function( opts ){
    this.post = opts.post;
  }
});
```

I think this idea can scale also for more complicate relations like `/forums/1/topics/3/replies`. You just have to take care of mantain the relation from every Collection to its parent.